# how to run maven project in eclipse and display program output on console

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have created a maven project in eclipse and I am able to build the project successfully. I have created a simple project which has just one class which is printing `hello world` to the console.

All I want is how can I see the hello world message on the eclipse console?
Right now when I do `run as` in eclipse, my project build successfully and this information is printed on console, but how can i see the hello world message? I am sorry if i am asking a basic level question but I am very new to maven

Comment: How can a class be printing "hello world"? Is this code in a main method? Please edit the question to clarify this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either click the run button [image], or run as > Java Application. A window will pop up and ask you to select your Java application. In the filter type in your main class and then click OK button.[image]